# Como descobrir a extensão do arquivo através do array de Bytes?

Tags: c#, mime-type

Gostaria de saber se é possível dar um get na extensão do arquivo através do Array de Bytes. Pois eu baixo um arquivo do servidor, e ele pode ser tanto .JPEG quanto .EPS, porém eu não estou conseguindo saber qual arquivo eu recebi e não consigo definir o MIME/Extensão do mesmo(estou preso em JPEG por exemplo). Segue exemplo:

```
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(image_url);
//Gostaria de reconhecer o formato para tratar a linha posterior
return File(myDataBuffer, "image/jpeg", "Imagem-"+imageID+".jpeg");
```

Comment: O `image_url` não termina com .jpeg ou .eps?

Comment: Não, o `image_url` não da acesso direto a imagem, é uma url com um Guid que autentica no servidor e retorna a imagem.

Comment: Será que essa ferramenta resolve: https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data

Comment: @Fernando não pois preciso de uma solução dentro do c#, fora dele não rola.

Comment: Se vc não encontrar uma solução melhor, você poderia executar o `TrID.exe` por dentro do C# da seguinte forma https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234448/run-shell-commands-using-c-sharp-and-get-the-info-into-string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Ache o MIME type

Tem o pacote [Mime-Detective](https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective). Tem no repositório NuGet. Você usaria assim:

```
byte[] myDataBuffer = myWebClient.DownloadData(image_url);
FileType fileType = myDataBuffer.GetFileType();
```

Ele lê os dados do cabeçalho do arquivo em si, não a extensão, como a maioria faz.

Uma outra solução, nativa do Windows, é usar a função [`FindMimeFromData`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107(v=vs.85).aspx) da `urlmon.dll`.

> Determina o tipo MIME dos dados providos

Segue um [exemplo de implementação](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62007/6241184), do SOen:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
// ...
[DllImport(@"urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private extern static System.UInt32 FindMimeFromData(
    System.UInt32 pBC,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzUrl,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pBuffer,
    System.UInt32 cbSize,
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] System.String pwzMimeProposed,
    System.UInt32 dwMimeFlags,
    out System.UInt32 ppwzMimeOut,
    System.UInt32 dwReserverd
);

public static string getMimeFromFile(string filename)
{
    if (!File.Exists(filename))
        throw new FileNotFoundException(filename + " not found");

    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
    {
        if (fs.Length >= 256)
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, 256);
        else
            fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    }
    try
    {
        System.UInt32 mimetype;
        FindMimeFromData(0, null, buffer, 256, null, 0, out mimetype, 0);
        System.IntPtr mimeTypePtr = new IntPtr(mimetype);
        string mime = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(mimeTypePtr);
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(mimeTypePtr);
        return mime;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return "unknown/unknown";
    }
}
```

A função retornará o MIME em string, que é exatamente o que você precisa. Se por algum motivo não conseguir, você receberá `unknown/unknown`.

## e então a extensão...

A extensão costuma ser a segunda parte do MIME type, pelo menos nos casos que você precisa: jpeg e eps. Sendo assim:

```
var mimeType = GetMimeType(file); // "image/jpeg"
var fileExtension = mimeType.Split('/').Last(); // "jpeg"
```

Sendo `GetMimeType(byte[])` o método que você fará para obter esse valor.

Comment: No caso não era o que foi perguntado

Comment: @vnbrs Resolveu meu problema, porém ainda tenho uma duvida relacionado ao MIME-Detective, quais formatos ele consegue detectar? pois quando recebo um .EPS ele diz que a extensão / MIME é txt

Comment: Deveria retornar algum desses: application/postscript, application/eps, application/x-eps, image/eps, image/x-eps. Não sei como ele se comporta quanto a esse tipo de arquivo, mas você pode tratar ou tentar o outro método com aquela dll que citei na resposta.

Comment: @vnbrs é que a biblioteca ainda não suporta EPS... mas de qualquer forma resolveu o meu problema, vou marcar como correta, utilizei essa biblioteca mesmo ! Inclusive vou colaborar com o projeto adicionando o EPS ;)